# Fix libboost-dev broken dependency

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, dependencies

I need to install fcl which depends on libboost-dev. However, libboost-dev depends on libboost1.46-dev and it refuses to install because I have the newer libboost1.48-dev.

I have followed instructions in the answer to this question: [apt and fixing incorect dependencies](https://superuser.com/questions/388428/apt-and-fixing-incorect-dependencies). However, I'm unable to run `debuild -uc -us` successfully. This is the output:

```
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package boost-defaults
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.48.0.2
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Steve M. Robbins 
 dpkg-source --before-build boost-defaults-1.48.0.2
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libboost1.48-dev (>= 1.48.1)
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting.
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
debuild: fatal error at line 1350:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

I currently have libboost1.48-dev installed and other 1.48 boost packages.

This link shows the source of the libboost-dev error:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/libboost-dev

What can I do to fix this?

Edit:
After checking dependencies, I realized I could uninstall `libboost1.48-dev` and use `libboost1.46-dev` instead.

I accepted terdon's answer because I think it is still useful information.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right version? It is complaining about `libboost1.48-dev (>= 1.48.1)` and `boost-defaults` seems to be `1.48.0.2`.

Comment: @terdon Synaptic says I have `libboost1.48-dev` version `1.48.0-3`

Comment: Well, the error you are getting is asking for a newer version. It wants `>= 1.48.1` and you have `1.48.0-3`. `1.48.0-3 < 1.48.1`

Comment: @terdon Synaptic only has version `1.48.0-3`. Do you know how to upgrade to a later version? Also, will the solution in http://superuser.com/questions/388428/apt-and-fixing-incorect-dependencies potentially poison my apt-get dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the solution you linked to should not affect anything but the package you are rebuilding. At least, there are no system wide changes or edits to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

As for the latest *stable* libboost, it seems to be 1.5.2.0. You can download it (or a slightly older release to be closer to what you have installed) from the boost sourceforge [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/) and compile from source.

Alternatively, you can [search packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libboost-dev) where you can find a .deb for 1.49.0.1. Depending on the dependencies (no pun intended) you will be able to install that with or without [apt pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html).